# fixing the toolbar i made with tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

i created a simple program with Tkinter but i have a small problem i have a graph and i am using `.grid()`
to place it and we`bar1.get_tk_widget().grid(column=2, row=3, rowspan=20, sticky="nesw")`
the result is:
[the first result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biLuP.png)

but then when i am aligning it to the left with column 0 like that `bar1.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=3, rowspan=20, sticky="nesw")`
the tool bar is centered as shown in figure 2
[the second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5UXP.png)

the question is how do i can fix the toolbar?

this is the full code link:
[my full code](https://github.com/Ahmedelsayed518/UV-Visible-GUI/tree/main/app)

Comment: Did you try setting `sticky='w'` in `grid(...)` on the toolbar?

Comment: @acw1668 i tried

Comment: You need to post a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 i have added my full code link

Comment: Adding `sticky='w'` in `toolbar.grid(...)` will put the toolbar at  the left side.  BTW, why do you create another frame `toolbar` inside `toolbar` class?  You can simply use `toolbar` class itself as it is a `Frame` as well.

Comment: thanks @acw1668 the problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I don't see your the rest of ur codes, here is my assumption:

- if you want to stack the picture on top of each other use .pack()
- you can use .place(x=100, y=100) to set an exact position.
- if you use grid, make sure you don't left any grid empty. For example: suppose that you have a grid 3x3, you need to have nine components (using columnspan or rowspan can reduce the numbers of the components). Based on your picture, you have only two images, so you have 2 choices:

```
# put it on top of each other
toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0) # should always start with 0
graph.grid(row=1, column=0) # it doesn't matter how big the number you set to the row, since you have only 2 two images, you can have only 2 rows

# put it side by side
toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0)
graph.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: Did you know comments in python starts with # and not //

Comment: my toolbar was created element by element so every icon takes a cell from the grid. does the figure of the graph has to be the same volume as the icons?

Comment: how do i can make my tool bar fixed and take all the row

Comment: i have added my full code link